# Load excel files using php/sql depending on filename

Tags: php, mysql, variables, load

I am using this code to load a file in my database. It is a php file that I upload on putty:

```
$Db->query('LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE \'/name 03.11.2015.csv\'  
        INTO TABLE '.$in_table.'
        FIELDS TERMINATED BY \',\'
        ENCLOSED BY \'"\'
        LINES TERMINATED BY \'\n\'
        IGNORE 8 ROWS
        (@date, number, @name)
        set date=str_to_date(@date,\'%Y-%m-%d\'),
            name= \'name\'
        ;');
```

Now I want to have a variable instead of a specific filename in the first line of the query :

```
$Db->query('LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE \'/path/name 03.11.2015.csv\'
```

So, I am using that and it seems that it is working :

```
$date = '.....';
$name = '.....';

    $Db->query('LOAD DATA INFILE \'/path/'.$name.' '.$date.'.csv\' 
            INTO TABLE '.$in_table.'
            FIELDS TERMINATED BY \',\'
            ENCLOSED BY \'"\'
            LINES TERMINATED BY \'\n\'
            IGNORE 8 ROWS
            (@date, number, @name)
            set date=str_to_date(@date,\'%Y-%m-%d\'),
                name= \'name\'
            ;');
```

But now I have to change my code because some files don't have this format in their filename : `'$name $date'`. Some examples are given below :

- name 2015-10-10
- rand name 2015-10-10

How can I check the filename given that the name is a specific value? I want to concat the filename and get the name and the date in order to find the file and then use the original filename in my code.

Comment: What do you mean by "a specific value"?

Comment: For example it is either "aaa" or "bbb". So, if there is an "aaa" in the string (filename) then the column name will be "aaa".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for this question but I still have an unanswered which is related to this one (link in the end). The answer for this question is here in this code :

```
$searchString = 'aaaa';
$Dates = array();

// Get all the files in my folder with the extension ".xlsx"
$files = glob('/path/*.xlsx');

// I create an array where I save all the .xlsx files that contain "aaaa" in the filename
$filesFound = array();

foreach($files as $file) {
    $name = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_FILENAME);

// Determines if there is a date and if the search string is in the filename. If yes, it puts the date and the filename in the arrays I created before
    if((strpos(strtolower($name),strtolower($searchString))) && (preg_match('~(\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4})~', $name, $matches))) {
         $filesFound[] = $name;
         $Dates[] = $matches[1];
         foreach($filesFound as $ftbu){
            $sql = 'LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE \'/path/'.$ftbu.'.xlsx\' INTO TABLE '.$dbtable.'
            FIELDS TERMINATED BY \',\' 
            ENCLOSED BY \'"\' 
            LINES TERMINATED BY \'\n\'
            (@date, number, @name)
            set date=str_to_date(@date,\'%Y-%m-%d\'),
                name = \'AAA\'
            ';
            $Db->query($sql);
            echo $Db->error;
        }
    } 
}
```

Link:
[Unanswered Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33503879/load-an-excel-file-into-mysql-where-cells-have-a-specific-format-date-accounti)